# Dynamically foreach loop limit php

Tags: php

I want to change dynamically foreach result limit.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($counts as $count) {
        if ($count < 1) {
            echo $count;
        }
    }
?>
```

I set `count` limit to 1 and result is `0`

Now i am not sure is it possible or not but my question is as example php stop loop after `count` = `0 < 1`, is there possible if `count` = `0 < 1` not found then automatically set limit `count` = `1 < 2` .

**My second question** is if i set a start date and end date to show a content.

`$sdate = 2015-07-20 0:0`

`$edate = 2015-07-30 0:0`

Now in php how to set this?

**php**

```
static $count = 0;
if($count < 1) {   
$this->data['count'] = $count++;
}
```

**tpl**

```
<?php echo $count; ?>
```

output is `0` . Now i want if i set `start date` and `end date` and when output `0` ended then auto define next module number `1`

Comment: you have no limits in there, other than the implied one: however many elements are in the array `$counts`.

Comment: Can you better describe what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want to pre-maturely stop your `foreach()` loop but also limit `$count` to 1 though it is a value contained in your `$counts` array.

Comment: That is a foreach loop. Which means it loops through each item. You need to google a for loop.

Comment: this is easily google-able, please look up your question on stackoverflow before you post

Comment: Now see updated question @MarcB

Comment: Yes i want to only limit one but not for each element/contained @the_pete

Comment: Now see updated question @HuangChen

Comment: Now see updated question @Hanoncs

Comment: You have an array `$counts` with no known content and no description what your loop should do with it. How could anyone be able to help? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and add more info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem may be the overuse of the variable name `$count`.
You are using it for 2 different purposes.  Try this:

```
$max = 3;

foreach ($counts as $count) {
    if ($count < $max) {
        echo $count;
    }
}
```

or explain your problem better.

Comment: Hay my actual question is i want to only limit one but not for each element/array